# ArcGIS Add-In Templates in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, arcgis, esri

Ín my understanding ArcGIS AddIn templates are only compatible with some Visual Studio Versions - e.g. 2008 should work fine, 2010 Express should not work, but 2010 Professional / Ultimate should be capable to use the templates too.

So I installed VS 2010 and the .NET Sdk from ESRI.
The templates do not show up.
Then I tried VS 2008 - I deinstalled VS 2010, installed 2008 and repaired the SDK installation - nothing showed up.
I even tried 2013 (which should not be compatible at all) and the corrosponding VS Express versions.

Nothing helped.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What ArcGIS for Desktop version are you using? Every ArcGIS version has support for different Visual Studio (.NET) version.

Comment: I'm using ArcGis 10.2.x . It's a educational copy. I'm on Windows 8.1 if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

[System Requirements](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.2/index.html#//01510000006n000000) state that Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 (C#, VB.NET) Professional, Premium, Ultimate Edition
or Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Visual Basic Express or Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Visual C# Express or Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 (C#, VB.NET) Professional, Premium, Ultimate Edition is required.

Also, ArcGIS for Desktop, ArcGIS Engine, or ArcGIS for Server is required to develop with ArcObjects SDK.

Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 is required also.

ArcObjects SDK for the Microsoft .NET Framework goes on top of all that.

In my case, I'm using ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1 with Visual Studio 2010 Professional. Add-In templates are installed and are showing up.

Comment: Thank you. I will try out that combination too later on.